# ViewModel is not updated until another row is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid like this:

```
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader">
</DataGrid>
```

And it's bound like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>
        {
            new Item()
        };

        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    private string _foo = string.Empty;
    public string Foo
    {
        get { return _foo; }
        set { _foo = value; }
    }

    private string _bar = string.Empty;
    public string Bar
    {
        get { return _bar; }
        set { _bar = value; }
    }
}
```

The program comes up with one Item. If I change Foo and Bar on the grid, it doesn't bind the changes, even if I switch between cells on the same row. But if i click on the next row, all the changes get bound at once. I'm guessing this has to do with the default UpdateSourceTrigger being set to LostFocus. However I want it to bind when the Cell loses focus, rather than the Row, since I have the grid configured for cell selection. How can I do this?

Comment: The wpf datagrid has transaction semantics and these are unlike other wpf controls.  The transaction scope is the entire row.  So a change is not applied until the "transaction" is complete.  Use IEditableObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of other way of changing `UpdateSourceTrigger` for auto generated column other then changing binding on `AutoGeneratingColumn` event

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" AutoGeneratingColumn="myDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

and then in code

```
private void myDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    var column = e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
    if (column != null)
    {
        var binding = column.Binding as Binding;
        if (binding != null) binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work.  A data grid column uses coercion to FORCE the update source trigger to explicit, even if you try to do it yourself like in your answer!

Comment: It worked when I tested it otherwise I would not post this as an answer. Also for manual columns I can set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to what I like and and it works and default `UpdateSourceTrigger` is not `Explicit` but `Default`

Comment: Ok, as long as you've proved it otherwise, but you should tell msdn that the docs are wrong.

Comment: I don't think I proved MSDN docs are wrong. So far I found nothing about forcing `Explicit` value. `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` is set to `Default` which means that it takes the value from `DepenedencyProperty` metadata (`FrameworkPropertyMetadata.DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger`). If you set it to anything else it will use that.